# What are the possible causes for Facebook's "Error validating application"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application uses Facebook's Graph API to pull user's information via /me, /wall, and so forth.

Sometimes users run into the error:

```
    "error": {
        "message": "Error validating application.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 190
    }
```

I can't find any reasons why this might be triggered as:

- Access token is valid, never-expires, and is associated to my
  application.
- I got the permissions to do the API calls
- API calls works fine afterward

In this condition, what might cause this?

Comment: It is a good question, I get this exception logged a couple of times a day and have always wondered what the cause was.  I've always written it off as a consequence of Facebook's reliance on flaky nosql technology like Cassandra :) Would be nice to get one of the Facebook employees who hang out here to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're receiving this error only for a small percentage of requests, you shouldn't need to do anything - the error happens when the provided access token is being checked for validity and the app's details can't be verified - usually an intermittent problem affecting only a tiny percentage of requests (unless you're forgetting to include the app ID in your SDK initialisation, in which case check that first)

Comment: The error percentage is indeed small(< 0.67%). It will be great if a  specific error message is return, so we know when to retry our request.